# about nominal switching capacity of the NO and NC sides of the Relays

Tags: relay

There is two kinds of contacts for relays - NO(Normal Open) and NC(Normal Close).

And I found that the nominal switching capacity of the NO side is always larger than the NC side.
For example, the ALQ relay of the Panasonic Inc. the specifications are as followed:

- NO side: 10A 125V AC, 5A 250V AC, 5A 30V DC
- NC side: 3A 125V AC, 2A 250V AC, 1A 30V DC

[image]

Question:

1. Why does there are differences for the nominal capacities between the NC and NO specification?
2. There is big difference in the specification values for the DC capacity in the above(NO: ***5A*** 30V DC, NC: ***1A*** 30V DC).
   The 5A capacity is sufficient for your project but the 1A is not.
   Will the current capacity be larger if the DC voltage is lower than 30V (eg. DC 5V)?

Comment: As far as I know, having different current ratings for the NO and NC terminals is not common. Please provide the part number of the relay you are referring to.  For your question #2, you have to take a look at the max. switching current vs. max. switching voltage curve of your particular relay. Most likely the max. current will not increase below 30VDC.

Comment: i think that the NO side and NC side may actually refer to two separate contact sets  ... the relay may have DPST contacts

Comment: To answer your very last question, no. You can't exceed the current rating, period.

Comment: @jsotola - that would make sense